# jQuery count characters within div?

Tags: jquery, html, css, count, character

I am trying to give a divs a different background according to their character length of the text inside.

This is my current code:

```
$('.aProduct .inner').each(function() {
    var length = $(this).text().length;    
    if(length > 20){
        $(this).css("background", "red");
    }
    else {
        $(this).css("background", "blue");
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="aProductHeader">
    <div class="omschrijving">
        <h3>omschrijving</h3>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="aProduct">
    <div class="omschrijving">
        <span class="entry inner">
            Toddler bestek blauw
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The code however doesn't work, and I'm horrible at jQuery. Any suggestions or tips or tutorials on how to fix my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**$.trim()**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/), Problem with your implementation it that it takes whitespace while calculating length.

> Remove the whitespace from the beginning and end of a string.

*Code*

```
var length = $.trim($(this).text()).length;
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kemhu/)

**EDIT**

A very good point by @KingKing

```
$('.inner').css('background', function(){    
    return $(this).text().trim().length > 20 ? 'red' : 'blue';
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/z7du5/)

Comment: it's better to use callback in a `css` method like this http://jsfiddle.net/z7du5/

Comment: it will only remove from start and end better is to use regex